# How to pass value of radio buttom with Html.ActionLink to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can i pass my radio value with action link to controller

this is my View Page code :

```
     foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       <div style="height:20px; background-color:#e1e1e1; border-radius:5px; padding:5px">
           <div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px">
               @Html.RadioButton("DealerRadio", item.id, new { @style = "margin-right:10px" })
           </div>
           <div style="float: left; margin-right: 30px">
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.company, new { @style = "margin-right:30px" }) 
           </div>
           <div style="float: left; margin-right: 30px">
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.address, new { @style = "margin-right:10px" })
           </div>
           <div style="float:right">
              @Html.Label("Tell:") @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contact)

           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
    }
  <p>@Html.ActionLink("BUY NOW", "PreOrder", new { Dealer_id = "", Tire_id = ViewBag.Tireid }, new { @class = "btn btn-Buy" })</p>
```

pleas help me to do this

Comment: You need javascript/jquery to handle the `.change()` event of you radio button and update the `href` attribute of the link, or better, just use a form with `FormMethod.Get` and post it.